# Blackscreen and cursor only after booting up KDE in an ArchLinux system

Tags: arch-linux, kde

Today I updated my system and answered yes to all doing so. After a reboot I only see the programs that are configured to start on startup and no windows frames are available (however I can interact with the on-top-of-all opened program windows)
My /var/log/pacman.log changes are reflected here:

> ```
> [2014-07-31 15:24] [PACMAN] Running 'pacman -Syu --color never'
> [2014-07-31 15:24] [PACMAN] synchronizing package lists
> [2014-07-31 15:24] [PACMAN] starting full system upgrade
> [2014-07-31 15:24] [PACMAN] removed kactivities (4.13.0-1)
> [2014-07-31 15:24] [PACMAN] removed polkit-qt (0.103.0-3)
> [2014-07-31 15:24] [PACMAN] upgraded ffmpeg (1:2.3-1 -> 1:2.3.1-1)
> [2014-07-31 15:24] [PACMAN] installed kactivities4 (4.13.3-1)
> [2014-07-31 15:24] [PACMAN] installed polkit-qt4 (0.112-1)
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with kactivities4.
Downgrade it by cding into /var/cache/pacman/pkg

```
cd /var/cache/pacman/pkg/
```

and installing the previously removed one

```
pacman -U kactivities-4.13.0-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz
```

I don't know why, but it works :p